# Spyder issue reporter when trying to run code

Tags: python, spyder

**Every time I try and run this code on spyder it comes up with an issue reporter window. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code that I'm trying to run. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.
The code is shown below:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import random  

coords = [random.randint(-5,5), random.randint(-5,5)]  
enemy_coords = [random.randint(-5,5), random.randint(-5,5)]  

plt.plot(coords[0], coords[1], 'bo', enemy_coords[0], enemy_coords[1], 'rx')  
plt.plot([1,2], [3,1])  
plt.xlim(-5,5)  
plt.ylim(-5,5)  
plt.show()  

slope = (1-3)/(2-1) #=-2  
#y = -2x + 5  
print(slope)  
print('Controls: Up(E), Down(D), Left(W), Right(R)')  

while enemy_coords[0] != coords[0] or enemy_coords[1] != coords[1]:  
    move = str(input(''))  
    move = move.upper()  
    if move == 'E':  
    if coords[0] != -2*(coords[1]) + 5: 
            print('a')  
        else:  
            coords[1] += 1  
    elif move == 'D':  
        coords[1] -= 1  
    elif move == 'W':  
        coords[0] -= 1  
    elif move == 'R':  
        coords[0] += 1  
    else:  
        coords = coords  
    if enemy_coords[0] > coords[0]:
        enemy_coords[0] -= 1  
    elif enemy_coords[0] < coords[0]: 
        enemy_coords[0] += 1  
    elif enemy_coords[1] > coords[1]: 
        enemy_coords[1] -= 1  
    elif enemy_coords[1] < coords[1]: 
        enemy_coords[1] += 1  
    plt.plot(coords[0], coords[1], 'o', enemy_coords[0], enemy_coords[1], 'x')  
    plt.plot([1,2], [3,1])  
    plt.xlim(-5,5)  
    plt.ylim(-5,5)  
    plt.show()
```

[issue reporter window that shows up when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhG17.png)

[Message that comes up just before the issue reporter appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEHkt.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you share the details shown in the report issue dialog?